# How do I optimize Ax = b such that every element of b is bigger than 0.5 and x has the lowest possible norm?

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-equations

As the title says I want to find x such that b, given by $Ax = b$
has ideally every element above 0.5 
And x has the lowest possible norm.

A is a symmetric definite positive matrix

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe formulate as a linear problem and solve with simplex algorithm.

Comment: what norm are we considering?

Comment: @LinAlg the norm 2

Comment: try YALMIP, should make formulating/solving easy